# How do you force Dropbox to save to a network location?

Tags: backup, nas, dropbox

### Problem

I am looking to close our dropbox business account. To do this, I first need to save the account contents account to our NAS.

When I attempt to move my dropbox folder to the network location, I get the following.

[image]

This is because...

> Dropbox doesn't support network locations due to issues that have come up before.<sup>1</sup>

### Attempted solutions

#### Dropbox.com

The web version of dropbox has a download limit that is significantly smaller than the data we have in Dropbox. I just get an error when I try to [download all files](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Dropbox-files-folders/Bulk-download-all-my-files/td-p/401238).

#### subst

I have tried `subst`, but cannot see how to make a drive that appears as a local drive, I have only been able to make another network drive.

#### Visual Subst

[Make mapped network drive appear as local drive](https://superuser.com/questions/1224079/make-mapped-network-drive-appear-as-local-drive) suggests [Visual Subst](https://www.ntwind.com/software/visual-subst.html), however, this is a paid product that provides no assurance it will actually work if I part with my $20. Besides, I am more than happy with a good old CLI.

#### NAS Client

QNAP provides HBS 3 and HybridMount<sup>2</sup> which can connect to Dropbox. After having left HybridMount for 12 hours it has downloaded almost nothing, so I am guessing that it only downloads what you are actually using, rather than everything. I have also looked into HBS 3 but again, cannot see a way to force it to just download all of Dropbox.

#### Art. 20 of the GDPR: *Right to data portability*

I have submitted a GDPR request to Dropbox for them to provide the data in a zip archive. It remains to be seen if they will comply.

### Constraints

- I am the Dropbox account admin.
- Dropbox account is on the "Teams Advanced" plan.
- Total size of dropbox account data ≈6TB
- I have been an IT guy for many years, so, I am the System Administrator. My voice is my passport.
- Our broadband connection provides 910mb/s down and 110mb/s up.
- NAS is a QNAP TS-453 Pro running firmware version 5.0.0.1932
- NAS has 24TB of capacity available.
- My laptop has 500GB of capacity and runs Windows 10.
- I also have Ubuntu & Mac machines that do not have Dropbox currently installed but are available if helpful.

---

1. dropboxforum.com. (2015). Sync with a network drive. [online] Available at: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Dropbox-installs-integrations/Sync-with-a-network-drive/td-p/99283 [Accessed 9 Feb. 2022].
2. [www.qnap.com](http://www.qnap.com). (n.d.). QNAP Hybrid Cloud Solutions with Dropbox Support Facilitate Effortless File Sharing and Collaboration | QNAP. [online] Available at: https://www.qnap.com/static/landing/2019/hybrid-cloud-news/dropbox/en/index.html [Accessed 9 Feb. 2022].

‌

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to QNAP support (via email),

> you would need to use HBS3 then select "active sync" to pull the data onto the NAS.

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating an **NTFS junction**? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/junction

The network drive probably has to be mapped to a drive letter (but I assume you already have this).

I've used this to move temp installer dirs from cluttery programs to different drives, seems to fool all of them so far.